# Spring MVC,Tile not rendering jsp page while running war file jetty Runner

Tags: java, maven, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

I am working with spring, hibernate,tile,jsp with jetty server.I have trapped on the following error,
The problem is tile not rendering page while running war file.
The error is with EL tag. But no issues while running `mvn clean jetty:run`.
I am not able to understand what is the problem while making package.
Every jar in my pom are there in lib folder where i unzip the war  and checked.
I am using `spring MVC 4.1`,`jstl-1.2`,`jetty-runner 9.3.3.v20150827`.
My web-app version is `web-app 2.5`. I have tried changing version of  `web-app` to 3 and added  `isELIgnored` `false` in my `jsp` page but not working.
I hope somebody will help,Thanks in advance.
Following is the error,

```
Caused by:
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/pages/login.jsp'.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1686)
    at com.zeetap.phrs.ctrl.account.corsfilter.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1088)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/pages/login.jsp'.
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:399)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:238)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.render(DefinitionRenderer.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/pages/login.jsp'.
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:63)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:267)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.doForward(ServletRequest.java:228)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractClientRequest.dispatch(AbstractClientRequest.java:57)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:397)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
An error occurred at line: 107 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/views/pages/login.jsp
The method proprietaryEvaluate(String, Class<String>, PageContext, null) is undefined for the type PageContextImpl
104: 
105:         <c:if test="true">
106:            <h4>
107:                <span><font color="green"><b> ${SUCCESS_MSSAGE}</b></font> </span>
108:            </h4>
109:        </c:if>
110:        <c:if test="${(ERROR_MSSAGE != null) }">
An error occurred at line: 110 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/views/pages/login.jsp
The method proprietaryEvaluate(String, Class<Boolean>, PageContext, null) is undefined for the type PageContextImpl
107:                <span><font color="green"><b> ${SUCCESS_MSSAGE}</b></font> </span>
108:            </h4>
109:        </c:if>
110:        <c:if test="${(ERROR_MSSAGE != null) }">
111:            <h4>
112:                <span><font color="red"><b> ${ERROR_MSSAGE}</b></font> </span>
113:            </h4>
An error occurred at line: 112 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/views/pages/login.jsp
The method proprietaryEvaluate(String, Class<String>, PageContext, null) is undefined for the type PageContextImpl
109:        </c:if>
110:        <c:if test="${(ERROR_MSSAGE != null) }">
111:            <h4>
112:                <span><font color="red"><b> ${ERROR_MSSAGE}</b></font> </span>
113:            </h4>
114:        </c:if> 
115:        <!-- BEGIN LOGIN FORM -->
An error occurred at line: 118 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/views/pages/login.jsp
The method proprietaryEvaluate(String, Class<Boolean>, PageContext, null) is undefined for the type PageContextImpl
115:        <!-- BEGIN LOGIN FORM -->
116:        <form class="login-form" action="authenticate.html" method="post">
117:            <c:choose>
118:            <c:when test="${'L' == loginpage }">style="display: block;"</c:when>
119:            <c:otherwise>style="display: none;"</c:otherwise>
120:            </c:choose>
121: 
An error occurred at line: 186 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/views/pages/login.jsp
The method proprietaryEvaluate(String, Class<Boolean>, PageContext, null) is undefined for the type PageContextImpl
183:        <!-- BEGIN FORGOT PASSWORD FORM -->
184:        <form class="forget-form" action="reqRestPwd.html" method="post"
185:            <c:choose>
186:            <c:when test="${'F' == loginpage }">style="display: block;"</c:when>
187:            <c:otherwise>style="display: none;"</c:otherwise>
188:            </c:choose>>
189: 
An error occurred at line: 306 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/views/pages/login.jsp
The method proprietaryEvaluate(String, Class<Object>, PageContext, null) is undefined for the type PageContextImpl
303: 
304:                    <form:option value="">
305:                    </form:option>
306:                    <form:options items="${reflist}"></form:options>
307: 
308: 
309: 
Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet.service(JettyJspServlet.java:107)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1088)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:74)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:265)
    ... 46 more
```

Comment: the exception is a good start, but it's hard to help you with your specific problem without any code. If you know where the exception is thrown, you should at least post the code to that part. Otherwise, it is anyone's guess what the issue is.

Comment: All my jsp pages shows Errors near the EL tag ${}, but i have already added jstl dependency, The problem occur while making war, No issues by running with jetty:run. Any guess why this happening while running war file only?

Comment: What do the errors say near the EL tag${}? I've run war files from within an ear so I'm not sure entirely if the problem has to do with running the war file only.

Comment: I have removed the EL tags and the page is loading,That is why i said problem with EL. I dont know the exact code where the error is thrown, because none of my page is loading,showing same error The method proprietaryEvaluate(String, Class<Object>, PageContext, null) is undefined for the type PageContextImpl on every jsp page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Remove all the  org.mortbay.jetty jsp and jstl dependencies from your pom.

2) Set Web.xml to this

```
<web-app
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="Your_Webapp_ID" version="3.0">
```

Comment: Yeah It started working while I removed the jsp and jstl dependencies .I have already changed my web.xml to version 3.0 the problem is not with web.xml. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: If anyone explain why it occur while adding those dependencies it would be a great knowledge.